# How to know Update is done for in simple mysqli query , Updated at least one row

Tags: php, mysqli

My Code is :

```
//Catch 
$myotp=$_GET["myotp"];
$rowid=$_GET["rowid"];

//Constructing the updat esql query
$update= "update order set dsotp ='$myotp' WHERE fsotp='$myotp' and id_order=$rowid";

//Excecuting the query
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$update);
```

It is working fine. But the problem is how to know from PHP code that it is updated the table?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` returns `TRUE or FALSE.` and also the result set.

So, you can try this:

```
 print_r($res);
```

PS: Also for the second part you can use `mysqli_affected_rows($conn);` to get the number of affected rows.

Comment: You're wrong. Returning result of mysqli_query is mixed. It can be True or False or Mysqli result

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Mentioned above only for success and error.

Comment: You answer is incorrect anyway 'cause you wrote that it returns boolean

Comment: Oh come on! This is not a battle! Correct the answer. That's all

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Updated.

Comment: Yes just now checked from the http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php we were using the wrong affected function

Answer (score 0):

You can check this way:

```
 $servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Refer:https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: am not using $conn->query. using mysqli_query only. will it work here ?

Comment: Pls check answer

Comment: That will return true if the query executed successfully but didn't actually update any records (for example if the requested record wasn't found or was already the requested value).  You need to check the number of affected rows too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if the query executed succesfully you should use the if statements provided above, however these do not check if there was any value updated. If you want that, you should use affected_rows.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

A basic example would be this:

```
if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
  var_dump($mysqli->affected_rows);

  if($mysqli->affected_rows == 1){
    return TRUE;
  } else{
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using this one $update= "update order set dsotp ='$myotp' WHERE fsotp='$myotp' and id_order_detail=$rowid and dsotp=''";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$update))
{
var_dump($mysqli->affected_rows);
  if($mysqli->affected_rows > 0)
   {
    return TRUE;
     } 
  else
   {
    return FALSE;
   }
}   But it is returning NULL only